# project variables and configuration in QtCreator custom wizards

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am creating a project *template* by using [Custom Wizards](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-project-wizards.html) (say, a "Hello World" project). Aside from including my files and classes, I would like some extra stuff to be **automatically added to the generated .pro file**, like `CONFIG+=compiler-configuration-stuff` or `LIBS+=extra-needed-library`, but the documentation does not say anything about this. Is it possible? How?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: once you exit the wizard you need to modify the `qmake` project file (`.pro`). search for "[qmake] config" or "[qmake] add libraries".

Comment: Thank you @UmNyobe. Yes, I know I can **manually** add those lines to the .pro file or to the qmake line in Projects > Build > Build Steps > qmake . I edited my question, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: You cannot do that. Usually a wizard is there for the simple and most common usage. Not to give the full potential.

Comment: Are you sure? It would be great for lazy programmers (like me) with  commonalities in the project files.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit .pro file in your wizard. The wizard files are in the following directory:

```
Qt-Dir/Tools/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/templates/wizards/
```

If you look at the directory there are some folders related to different wizards. For example if you look in to the "helloworld/qmake" folder, there you can see a "project.pro" file and a "wizard_sample.xml" file. You can edit the xml file to have your custom wizard.

"project.pro" is a template pro file. You can edit it and next time you create a project by that wizard, your custom pro would be created for the project.